# IdentityServer4 : MVCC Looping Back & Forth After Login

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I'm attempting to sign in to an MVC application using [IdentityServer4](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) along with [Asp.Net Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).


User is redirected to the identity server, they enter their credentials and they are redirected back to the MVC app when successful.
However it appears that the MVC app isn't saving the token and is redirecting back to IdentityServer.
When I add an Event Handler `OnTokenValidated` within the MVC app, I can see that there is a User Principle and they are Authorized, after the cycle is complete, `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider` is invoked and the cycle starts again.

**MVCC - Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add Custom Services.
        services.AddCustomAuthorization(Configuration);

        // Add Required Services.
        services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        {
            AuthorizationPolicy policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        })
            .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions()
        {
            Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always,
            HttpOnly = Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy.HttpOnlyPolicy.Always,
        });

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}")
            .RequireAuthorization();
        });
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services"></param>
    /// <param name="configuration"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IServiceCollection AddCustomAuthorization(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme)
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", "IdentityServer", options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
            options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;
            options.SaveTokens = true;
       
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:44308/";
            options.ClientId = "3468";
            options.ClientSecret = "##";
            options.ResponseType = "code";
            options.ReturnUrlParameter = "https://localhost:44346/Home/Foo";

            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
            {
                // Events Added To Inspect Data.
                OnTokenResponseReceived = async context =>
                {
                    await Task.Yield();
                },

                OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async context =>
                {
                    await Task.Yield();
                },

                OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                {
                    await Task.Yield();
                },

                OnTicketReceived = async context =>
                {
                    await Task.Yield();
                },
                OnMessageReceived = async context =>
                {
                    await Task.Yield();
                },
                OnUserInformationReceived = async content =>
                {
                    await Task.Yield();
                },
            };
        });

        return services;
    }
}
```

**IdentityServer- Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public static string CertificatePath { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="configuration"></param>
    /// <param name="environment"></param>
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        CertificatePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(environment.ContentRootPath, "##.pfx");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly bool IsIIS = NativeMethods.IsAspNetCoreModuleLoaded;

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        services.AddCustomIdentityServer(Configuration);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        // Removed To Shorten Sample.
        EnsureDatabasesAsync(app).Wait();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        });
    }


public static class Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services"></param>
    /// <param name="configuration"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IServiceCollection AddCustomIdentityServer(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        string migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

        // Add Asp Identity DbContext.
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sql =>
            {
                sql.UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery);
                sql.EnableRetryOnFailure(maxRetryCount: 5, System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), errorNumbersToAdd: null);
                sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly);
            });
        });

        // Add Asp Identity.
        services.AddIdentity<AppIdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Builder IdentityServer4
        // Using Users From AspNetIdentity.
        IIdentityServerBuilder builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
        })
            .AddAspNetIdentity<AppIdentityUser>()
            .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
                  {
                      options.ConfigureDbContext = b =>
                            b.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sql =>
                            {
                                sql.UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery);
                                sql.EnableRetryOnFailure(maxRetryCount: 5, System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), errorNumbersToAdd: null);
                                sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly);

                            });
                  })
            .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                  {
                      options.ConfigureDbContext = b =>
                            b.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sql =>
                            {
                                sql.UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery);
                                sql.EnableRetryOnFailure(maxRetryCount: 5, System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), errorNumbersToAdd: null);
                                sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly);

                            });

                      options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
                  });

#if DEBUG
        builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
#else
        X509Certificate2 x509Certificate = null;
        x509Certificate = new X509Certificate2(Startup.CertificatePath);
        builder.AddSigningCredential(x509Certificate);
#endif

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddMicrosoftAccount(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = "##";
                options.ClientSecret = "##";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
            });

        return services;
    }
}
```

**IdentityServer - Account Controller**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<AppIdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<AppIdentityUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly IIdentityServerInteractionService _interaction;
    private readonly IClientStore _clientStore;
    private readonly IAuthenticationSchemeProvider _schemeProvider;
    private readonly IEventService _events;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userManager"></param>
    /// <param name="signInManager"></param>
    public AccountController(IIdentityServerInteractionService interaction, 
        UserManager<AppIdentityUser> userManager, 
        SignInManager<AppIdentityUser> signInManager, 
        IClientStore clientStore,
        IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemeProvider,
        IEventService events)
    {
        this._userManager = userManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userManager));
        this._signInManager = signInManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(signInManager));
        this._interaction = interaction ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(interaction));
        this._clientStore = clientStore ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(clientStore));
        this._schemeProvider = schemeProvider ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(schemeProvider));
        this._events = events ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(events));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="returnUrl"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        // Check There Is A ReturnUrl So We Dont Forever Loop.
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && returnUrl == "/") return Ok();

        // Redirect To The ReturnUrl.
        return User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? Redirect(returnUrl) : View();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="identityLoginModel"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost]
#if !DEBUG
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
#endif
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromForm] IdentityLoginModel identityLoginModel)
    {
        try
        {
            AppIdentityUser identityUser = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(identityLoginModel.EmailAddress);

            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult signinResult = 
                await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(identityUser.UserName, identityLoginModel.Password, identityLoginModel.IsPersistent, false);

            if (signinResult.Succeeded)
            {
                await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(identityLoginModel.EmailAddress, identityUser.Id, identityUser.UserName));
                return Redirect(IdentityLoginModel.ReturnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                // TODO: Return Model With Unauthorized Message Attached.
                return Unauthorized();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // TODO: Log error(s)
            return Problem(statusCode: 500);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, by changing the `DefaultScheme` in `services.AddAuthentication` to `IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;` my cookies matched which then redirected me to the correct page.